# how to aggregate multiple columns and generate a formated string in python

Tags: pyspark

I have table/dateframe with the following structure

```
**userid   item    createdon**
user1    item1   2020-10-01
user1    item2   2020-10-02
user1    item3   2020-10-03
user2    item4   2020-01-01
user2    item1   2020-03-03
...
```

for each userid, I need to generate a string in a format like this:

for user1:

```
{ "date": "2020-10-01",
  "item": {"display": "item1"}
},
{ "date": "2020-10-02",
  "item": {"display": "item2"}
},
{ "date": "2020-10-03",
  "item": {"display": "item3"}
}
```

for user2:

```
{ "date": "2020-01-01",
  "item": {"display": "item4"}
},
{ "date": "2020-03-03",
  "item": {"display": "item1"}
}
```

I am using pyspark. I wonder if I could achieve this by utilizing map transformation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this output wanted? A file per user?

Comment: I will use it to generate the part of a json object.

Answer (score 1):

I could get the example working. It writes out one file per user.

Ref : [Spark: write JSON several files from DataFrame based on separation by column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725884/spark-write-json-several-files-from-dataframe-based-on-separation-by-column-val)

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [
        ("user1", "item1", "2020-10-01"),
        ("user1", "item2", "2020-10-02"),
        ("user1", "item3", "2020-10-03"),
        ("user2", "item4", "2020-01-01"),
        ("user2", "item1", "2020-03-03")
      ]

df1Columns = ["userid", "item", "createdon"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)
df1.printSchema()
df1.show(truncate=False)

partialSchema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), nullable=True)
                           , StructField("item", StructType([StructField("display", StringType(), nullable=True)]), nullable=True)
                        ])

actualSchema = StructType([StructField("userid", StringType(), nullable=True)
                           , StructField("dict", partialSchema, nullable=True)
                        ])

res_df = df1.rdd.map(lambda row: Row(row[0], {"date": row[2], "item" : {'display':row[1]}}))\
    .toDF(actualSchema)

res_df.show(20, False)

res_df.repartition(col("userid")).select(col("userid"), col("dict.*")).write.partitionBy("userid").json("./helloworld/data/")
```

The last line writes out two files one per each user.

Content of first user file:

```
{"date":"2020-10-01","item":{"display":"item1"}}
{"date":"2020-10-02","item":{"display":"item2"}}
{"date":"2020-10-03","item":{"display":"item3"}}
```

Content of second user file:

```
{"date":"2020-01-01","item":{"display":"item4"}}
{"date":"2020-03-03","item":{"display":"item1"}}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much.